# .exe made using py2exe not doing anything

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I'm using Python 2.7.9 on Windows 7 x86

the file i'm trying to make into an executable has the following source code:

```
import Tkinter
root=Tkinter.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Yeah, not much, just an empty window.

The setup file is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
s=raw_input("Name:")
s=s+".py"
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': s}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

When i run the exe, nothing happens, even when using cmd. I get no errors either, it just... does nothing.

Comment: How are you running the script? Are you doing it via a command prompt, and not seeing any output or errors at all?

Comment: I ran setup.py both in cmd and using windows. It does give me output, and quite a lot of it, the exe file just isnt working. I haven't noticed any errors.

Answer (score -1):

I've always found cx_freeze easier to use on Windows 
http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Can it create a standalone exe?